# SwiftUI in Swift Playground Preview Size Looks Incorrect

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

### Issue

I have this basic boilerplate format for trying out Swiftui in playgrounds. The preview live view is always this small rectangle. I don't know if this is a bug in Swift Playgrounds or am I missing something else? (see picture)

### Code

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Updated Code / Screenshot

It was suggested that I provide a `UIHostingController` and set the `preferredContentSize`. So I tried that and no change. Same problem. See screenshot below.

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}

let contentView = ContentView()
let hostingViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
hostingViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 700, height: 800)

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(hostingViewController)
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

When using your original code you can use the `.frame` modifier with the ContentView(). You have to provide a with and height, when choosing these values big enough your view should be more appealing.
Adding the modification your code could look like this:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(
    ContentView()
        .frame(width: 500.0, height: 500.0)
        //provide a width and hight of your choice
)
```

The following preview will be provided, when running the code:
[image: Preview provided by the code in a Xcode Playground.]

Answer (score 0):

You can make the preview size bigger like this:

```
let contentView = ContentView()
let hostingViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)

/// give us some more room
hostingViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 700, height: 800)

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(hostingViewController)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I'm not seeing any changes when I run the playground preview. I'm running Xcode 12.01 I don't know if there is a bug for this build. I will be posting an updated image shortly.

Comment: Weird, I just ran and got the same result (but on a different playground, it works).

Comment: Just made a view controller with UIKit and got a *huge* preview size... https://imgur.com/a/GGKclAf. I'm running Xcode 12.0

Comment: Well, then clearly something is wrong with my Xcode setup.  Version 12.0.1. I need to investigate. Thanks for providing a screenshot.

Comment: Np, but when I ran your code, I got the same tiny preview. I probably need to investigate my setup too.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your "Text" inside **NavigationStack** which will show you the preview just like in the project.